# Cant handle CPU Max Clock!

Tags: overclocking, setcpu, clock-speed

Hello Masters of Android! I am using Galaxy S5(SM-G906S)(Qualcomm SnapDragon 801). I have a problem. The problem is that I can't handle CPU Max Clock.. Available Max Clock is 2457Mhz but system always set to 1728Mhz.. It causes some lags... How can I Solve this.. I already did factory reset using Kies...

Comment: Your CPU governor used by kernel would most likely be the issue. Are you using stock or a custom kernel? If custom one, which kernel is it? What are you using to detect the clock speed? Have you used anything to change governor or clock speed? What is it? Actually, which governor is the device currently using? We can assume that the device is rooted, right?

Comment: @Fitelord Yes, I rooted. And I am using Stock Kernal. I am using Device Manager & Kernal Aduitor app to control Cpu clock... I donot know what is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Actually, even if you know that a kernel can allow you to overclock your CPU to a certain speed, there's a little file which consists of a frequency limit.

This file is to be found into **/sys/kernel/cpufreq**, and its name is **hardlimit**. Inside it, you'll find the maximum frequence, defined in Hz. For instance, and for your case as well, its content will be **1728000**, which is equal to 1728MHz.

By using a root file editor, which usually integrates a text editor feature, you can edit this limit to the desired frequence (in your case, **2457000**. Please notice that, even if you succeed in editing it, the file may be rewritten after a reboot. Given that, make sure to check if your kernel supports init.d, and, if yes, write a little script to change the file at boot.

Comment: It was just throttling